# generating function of summation equation

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Find a formula for the generating function
$(1)_{(k)} + (2)_{(k)}x + (3)_{(k)}x^2 + (4)_{(k)}x^3 + (5)_{(k)}x^4 + ... = \sum_{n\geq 0}(n+1)_{(k)}x^n$.
The subscript $k$ is falling factorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denoting with $n^{\underline{k}}=n(n-1)\cdots(n-k+1)$ the *[falling factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials)* we observe the first $k-1$ terms of the series vanish.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{n\geq k}n^{\underline{k}}x^{n-1}}&=\sum_{n\geq k}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!}x^{n-1}\\
> &=\frac{k!}{x}\sum_{n\geq k}\binom{n}{k}x^n\tag{1}\\
> &=\frac{k!}{x}\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{n+k}{n}x^{n+k}\tag{2}\\
> &=k!x^{k-1}\sum_{n\geq 0}\binom{-k-1}{n}(-x)^n\tag{3}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{k!x^{k-1}}{(1-x)^{k+1}}}\tag{4}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out $x$ and use binomial coefficients $\binom{n}{k}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ for convenience.
- In (2) we shift the index $n$ by $k$ to start with $n=0$.
- In (3) we factor out $x^k$ and use the binomial identity $\binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q$.
- In (4) we use a binomial *[series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*.